# Warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

> Warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'color:red'>

and this my code :

```
$db->query("UPDATE members set id='{$this->test['id']}', 
     lvl='{$this->userlvl}', ip='{$this->test['IP']}', 
     time='{$this->test['time']}', 
     linechat='{$this->test['msg']}' 
     WHERE user='{$this->test['name']}'");
```

I'm a beginner so please tell me what is must be ^^

I have tried this

```
$fixchat = mysql_real_escape_string($this->test['msg']);
$fixname = mysql_real_escape_string($this->test['name']);

$db->query("UPDATE members set id='{$this->test['id']}',
     lvl='{$this->userlvl}', ip='{$this->test['IP']}', 
     time='{$this->test['time']}', linechat='{$fixchat}' 
     WHERE user='{$fixname}'");
```

but I got this error :

> Warning:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\wellington\'' at line 1...

Comment: Print out the query after the substitution.

Comment: i have got this :  'set id='11276760', lvl='member', ip='', time='1374777237', linechat='{ .. its not completed because the syntax error

Comment: . . Store the sql in a separate variable, print it out, and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the values in your `$this->test` array has double quote characters in it.  Every dynamic element to a query string must be escaped by passing it through the appropriate escape function (in your case `mysql_real_escape_string()`).  That will escape the quotes so the string is interpreted correctly.

Side note: You should be using the mysqli PHP library instead of mysql, which is deprecated.  Also, a better alternative solution is to use parameterized queries.

Comment: Hi, can i know what it should be ?

Comment: What what should be? The code? Write a new set of variables set from passing your existing ones through the escape function.

Answer (score 0):

solved by : addslashes function

```
$fixchat = addslashes($this->test['msg']);
$fixname = addslashes($this->test['name']);

$db->query("UPDATE members set id='{$this->test['id']}',
     lvl='{$this->userlvl}', ip='{$this->test['IP']}', 
     time='{$this->test['time']}', linechat='{$fixchat}' 
     WHERE user='{$fixname}'");
```